# Passing a URL to CakePdf

Tags: cakephp, wkhtmltopdf

*Using CakePHP 2.6.7*

When generating a PDF using [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) I can simply run from the command line `wkhtmltopdf http://url/of/my/website some_name.pdf` but I can find no way to pass a URL in this manner through [CakePdf](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf) when using the Wkhtmltopdf engine. The closest I can get is using `file_get_contents(http://my/website)` and then manually going through the result and turning relative URLs for stylesheets/scripts into full URLs.

Is there a way to pass a URL to CakePdf? Alternatively, what would be the best way to go through a load of HTML and turn the relative links into full ones?

**Partial Solution**

For the moment I have managed to use the following code to manipulate the links on the page and replace them with the full urls.

```
$parsed_web_address = parse_url($this->request->data['ArmawareHtmlToPdf']['web_address']);
$root_web_address = $parsed_web_address['scheme'] . '://' . $parsed_web_address['host'] . '/';

$html_string = str_replace('href="/', 'href="' . $root_web_address, $html_string);
$html_string = str_replace('src="/', 'src="' . $root_web_address, $html_string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As far as I'm aware you can't pass a URL through CakePdf. The entire purpose of the plugin is to convert html generated from your Cakephp app to wkhtmltopdf. So it wouldn't make much sense to pass a url to a external html source.

My suggestion would be to use wkhtmltopdf directly using `proc_open()`. Take a look at the WkHtmlToPdfEngine.php file in the CakePdf plugin for an example of using this with wkhtmltopdf.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that there would be a way to still access this functionality of wkhtmltopdf through CakePdf too. Temporarily I've solved it with the solution I've put on the question and I'll implement removing CakePdf and accessing wkhtmltopdf directly later.